# Integrate XAML pages into Storyboard

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin

This is a slightly tricky question to explain

I am currently looking at using Xamarin for doing our app development

I am happy with using Xamarin going forwards,  however I wanted to use Telerik's charting component for Xamarin.  From looking at various examples, it appears as though everything is defined in XAML, i.e. the entire user interface.  This is not a good approach in my mind, because I dont want to be forced to change my entire application over to use XAML which will obviously then lose the native controls from Apple

So my question is how can I integrate a XAML page into a story board?

This chart will only be used in 1 view, and there are many more besides this one

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common approaches to creating apps with Xamarin.

Xamarin Forms allows you do define a UI in XAML or code that is then compiled down to a native Android/iOS/WinPhone UI.

The other approach is to write native UI for each platform, utilizing the native UI toolkit.  This gives you full access to the UI stack of each platform, but requires more work for a cross platform app, because you have to write the UI multiple times.  For iOS, this approach still allows you to use Storyboards and NIBs.

Comment: Thanks it looks like I will have to try the xamarin forms approach I have been put off by the appearance of teleriks demo using xamarin forms because it doesn't look native. I want a navigation system that looks native for example a native table view of contacts whereas their example doesn't look like a native table view. I think that's probably more of an issue with Telerik than xamarin

Comment: Telerik has their own cross-platform toolkit with is HTML driven, not native.  That might be what you're seeing.  But they also have chart controls that specifically target Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Yep that's what I have seen I want to use xamarin forms not their html based framework I now have spotted a big issue with using xamarin forms where it looks like their map integration is not great but I will raise a new question for that

Comment: [FYI: I work at Telerik] 

Hi Paul, We do not offer a ListView control at the moment … so I am not sure if you have taken look at the right product’s demos. You can find our products at http://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui. Since we don't provide a ListView component, could you provide more details about the expected behavior and where exactly did you notice the “non-native” behavior?